# Is there a homotopical analogue of short exact sequence?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, field-with-one-element

For $R$-modules for a commutative ring $R$, submodules and quotients are put on roughly the same footing; the kernel of a quotient is an injection into the source, and the cokernel of this injection is the original quotient. Similarly, the kernel of the cokernel of an injection is itself. This is (part of) a property of general categories called *protomodularity*. This property generally fails in the category of $R$-semimodules (commutative monoids with an $R$-action) for $R$ a commutative semiring.

This causes problems when trying to generalize algebraic geometry to semirings. For example, consider the quotient map $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{B}$ where $\mathbb{B}$ is the boolean semifield. Since $\mathbb{B}$ has no further quotients, we should expect this map to act like a closed immersion of a point into $Spec(\mathbb{N})$. The usual AG formalism then tells us that the image of this point is the kernel of the map of semirings; but the kernel is $(0)$! Topologically, we should not be expecting $(0)$ to be a closed point here, so something is quite wrong. Specifically, the cokernel of $(0)\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ is not $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{B}$, even though the latter map is a quotient.

Back in the commutative ring situation, one way to encapsulate in a single object a submodule/quotient pair is as a short exact sequence of $R$-modules. The idea then is to consider closed subspaces of $R$ as short exact sequenced of $R$-modules

$$0\rightarrow I\rightarrow R\rightarrow R/I\rightarrow 0$$

so that for any left exact sequence $$0\rightarrow I\rightarrow R\rightarrow R'$$
there is a unique closed subspace of $R$ involving that map:

$$0\rightarrow I\rightarrow R\rightarrow R/I\rightarrow 0$$

which could be considered the "scheme-theoretic image".

---

Usually, to avoid issues arising from lack of cokernel = kernel correspondence, one switches from homological algebra to homotopical algebra. This is the approach taken in much of noncommutative algebraic geometry, as well as Durov's algebraic geometry. In the latter, he gives a model structure on the category of simplicial commutative monoids (or any other category of modules of a "generalized ring").

**To be precise:** I am asking if there is a Dold-Kan-style analogue of short exact sequences in simplicial commutative monoids, which would allow us to do algebraic geometry over $\mathbb{N}$, e.g. by turning maps of semirings into "short exact sequences" which represent the kernel of the map.

The idea is that we would start defining general semiring algebraic geometry (not just for tropical semirings, but for anything) with closed subspaces, and work our way towards open subspaces and eventually schemes. This would serve to better explain confusing apparent geometric phenomena in generalized algebraic geometry a la Durov.

Sorry if this question ends up naïve; I'm not too familiar with homotopical algebra (or even much homological algebra such as chain homotopy), but this came up naturally in my research on arithmetic semirings.

Comment: I should let a homotopy theorist answer, but wouldn't the analogue be $fibre\to X\to Y$, or dually $X\to Y\to cofibre $, or a *distinguished triangle* in the appropriate setting?

Comment: I am so unfamiliar with derived AG of any kind, but a brief survey reveals that a distinguished triangle would be helpful; however they seem to only make sense in the setting of the homotopy/derived category of an Abelian category (whereas the category we are considering is the homotopy category of CMon, which is not abelian)

Comment: Hmm, actually yes, it seems a nonabelian version of distinguished triangles is exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: Triangles do not exist in unstable homotopy theory. In that case you have left and right triangles, which are like cokernels of submodules and kernels of quotients, respectively, but they don’t coincide. You have to figure out which one is useful for  you.

Comment: What would I end up with if I stabilized the resulting infinity-category from the model structure on simplicial commutative monoids?